# jQuery live calc multirow input

Tags: php, jquery, input, multirow

This is my code:

```
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){ 
        echo '<input type="text" class="count value'. $i .'">';
        echo '<input type="text" class="count '. $i .'value">';
        echo '<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result'. $i .'"><p>';
    }
        echo '<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="total"><p>';
    ?>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".count").keyup(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var val1 = +$(".value"+ i).val();
            var val2 = +$("."+ i +"value").val();
            $("#result" + i).val(val1*val2);
        }
   });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".count").keyup(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var vala = 0;
            vala += +$("#result"+ i).val();
            }
            $("#total").val(vala);
   });
});
```

First part of code works great. 
Return multiplication two inputs to `id=result$i.`

I have a problem with last one `id=total.` 
It should return sum of all result **X inputs** 
but now only return the last multiplication. 
Do You have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by grouping the related `input` elements together in a containing `div`, using DOM traversal to retrieve the needed values, and joining the two `for` loops together. Try this:

```
<div class="group">
    <input type="text" class="count valueA" />
    <input type="text" class="count valueB" />
    <input type="text" class="result" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
<!-- repeat the above as needed. Note that the incremental id is no longer needed -->

<p>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="total" />
</p>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".count").keyup(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.group').each(function() {
            var $group = $(this);
            var valA = +$group.find('.valueA').val() || 0;
            var valB = +$group.find('.valueB').val() || 0;
            var result = valA + valB;
            total += result;
            $group.find('.result').val(result);
        });
        $("#total").val(total);
   });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/axb3Lakp/)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have defined variable `vala` to 0 in for loop. which should be outside for loop:

```
$(".count").keyup(function(){
    var vala= 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vala += $("#result"+ i).val();
    }
    $("#total").val(vala);
 });
```

Comment: Now it's worked but total sum is string, i need value:/  How can i change it ?